# Placing a method in a timer to slow it down for Emotiv Epoc

Tags: c#, timer, pooling

I'm new to c#.

**The problem**:

I'd like to run a method within a timer, but the method returns/needs arguments not in the timers set of arguments.

**The reason**: The method is called regularly (EPOC Emotiv headset) and I would like it to be called only once a second.

It is called (I think) by a function:

EmoEngine.Instance.CognitivEmoStateUpdated += new EmoEngine.CognitivEmoStateUpdatedEventHandler(Instance_CognitivEmoStateUpdated);

*the method that runs* (too regularly) is:

void Instance_CognitivEmoStateUpdated(object sender, EmoStateUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            EmoState es = e.emoState;
            EdkDll.EE_CognitivAction_t currentAction = es.CognitivGetCurrentAction();
         }

The sotware already comes with a timer runs to process events every second:

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            engine.ProcessEvents();
         }

**I wish I could simply place the method aboce (Instance_Cogn...) in the timer, an I think that would sove the problem**..

What is the best way to do this please?

Many thx.

Comment: As per your post you have created an event "CognitivEmoStateUpdated" and when this event happens you are calling Instance_CognitivEmoStateUpdated function. You want to call Instance_CognitivEmoStateUpdated once in a second, so what is the mean of binding this function to event.

Answer (score 1):

Use System.Threading.Timer instead of Timer Control.
Time class of threading gives you the facility to pass the arguments and use the output of function in code.

```
   // Create the delegate that invokes methods for the timer.
   TimerCallback timerDelegate = new TimerCallback(CheckStatus);

   // Create a timer that waits one second, then invokes every second.
   Timer timer = new Timer(timerDelegate, arguments,1000, 1000);
```

[Refer the sample code](http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~lok/csharp/refdocs/System.Threading/types/Timer.html)

Comment: Unfortunately I get a CS0123 Error when I use:     TimerCallback timeCB = new TimerCallback(Instance_CognitivEmoStateUpdated); although the method   void Instance_CognitivEmoStateUpdated(object sender, EmoStateUpdatedEventArgs e)
        { } appears there.  Do I need to specifiy a library?

Comment: share your code in post. How many args you want to pass to timer.

Comment: namespace LoadUserProfile
{public partial class Cognate : Form
   { EmoEngine engine = EmoEngine.Instance; public Cognate()
   { InitializeComponent(); }
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {EmoEngine.Instance.EmoStateUpdated += new EmoEngine.EmoStateUpdatedEventHandler(Instance_EmoStateUpdated);
    EmoEngine.Instance.CognitivEmoStateUpdated += new EmoEngine.CognitivEmoStateUpdatedEventHandler(Instance_CognitivEmoStateUpdated);
   engine.Connect();} void Instance_CognitivEmoStateUpdated(object sender, EmoStateUpdatedEventArgs e)
        { code to run every 1 second}

Comment: the timer only needs to run the method, I'm not sure I need to send any arguments to it. Thank you :)